# Find and replace line in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im new to scripting in sheets and im trying to make a script that find a line in a sheet and replace the values of another cell in that line, any ideas?
I tried somthing like this but it doesnt work like i want to
`    function replaceRow() {

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventario"); 
  var lastRowEdit = editSheet.getLastRow();

  for(var i = 2; i <= lastRowEdit; i++)
  {  

   if(editSheet.getRange(i,1).getValue() == 'COLINA')
   {
     editSheet.getRange('A' + i + ':I' + i).setValues([['Move!E12', 'Move!E13', 'C'+i, 'D'+i, 'E'+i, 'F'+i, 'G'+i, 'H'+i, 'I'+i,]]);     
   }    
  }
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to avoid is repeated `getValue()/setValue()`.  I do this by getting all the values from the sheet rather than `getValue()` each row.  Next I examine the value in column A (Array index 0) for a match.  Then unfortunately because I don't know the original data structure I have to write a row that matches the seach criteria.  If each row has the same number of columns I could have modified the values and the used 1 `setValues()` to write all the updated values to the sheet.

```
function replaceLine() {
    try {
      let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
      let editSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      let values = editSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      values.shift(); // remove headers

      for(var i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {  
        if( values[i][0] === 'COLINA'  ) {
          let row = i+2;
          editSheet.getRange(row,1,1,9).setValues([['Move!E12', 'Move!E13', 'C'+row, 'D'+row, 'E'+row, 'F'+row, 'G'+row, 'H'+row, 'I'+row,]]);     
        }    
      } 
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log("Error in replaceLine: "+err);
    }
  }
```

Refernce

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)